# Get json data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The question I am asking is a basic question because I am new in json and ajax.

so I have a json data of `name , task , date and status` I am getting data through ajax but it  is not showing in on my page.

[image: responce]

**my ajax code is this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({
        url: "getdata.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function( json ) {
            $( "<h1/>" ).text( json.name ).appendTo( "body" );
            $( "<div class=\"content\"/>").html( json.task ).appendTo( "body" );
        },
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    }); 
});
```

**this is my json data:**

```
[
  {"name":"Usman ","task":"Getting work","date":"27-07-2014 12:28:45 PM","status":"1"},
  {"name":"Hamza","task":"Starting work","date":"27-07-2014 12:29:36 PM","status":"1"},
  {"name":"Hamza","task":"Geted","date":"27-07-2014 2:04:07 PM","status":"1"},
  {"name":"Hamza","task":"Start work","date":"02-08-2014 3:56:37 PM","status":"1"}
]
```

I don't know why It is not appending html data but it is showing complete alert.

I have added fiddle even if it is not working.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buS2j/)

Comment: Complete doesn't necessarily mean success.

Comment: The JSON is an array of objects.

Comment: probably you forgot `JSON.parse(json)` in success section, if json is a string of course, please, put `debugger;` in success section, open console by `F12` and you will see what happens here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i see you actually getting results so i guess you do have a success. You do have a flaw though. You are trying to access properties directly, but your json is an array of objects and not an object.

You need to do a `foreach` itteration.

```
json.forEach(function (entry) {
    $( "<h1/>" ).text( entry.name ).appendTo( "body" );
    $( "<div class=\"content\"/>").html( entry.task ).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your Json like

```
{
  "jsontext":[
    {"name":"Usman ","task":"Getting work","date":"27-07-2014 12:28:45 PM","status":"1"},
    {"name":"Hamza","task":"Starting work","date":"27-07-2014 12:29:36 PM","status":"1"},
    {"name":"Hamza","task":"Geted","date":"27-07-2014 2:04:07 PM","status":"1"},
    {"name":"Hamza","task":"Start work","date":"02-08-2014 3:56:37 PM","status":"1"}
  ]
}
```

and the ajax code should be as

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/getdata.txt',
  complete: function (data) {
    if (data.responseText != "") {
      var NewTxt = data.responseText;
      NewTxt = NewTxt.replace(/\n/g, "");
      NewTxt = NewTxt.replace(/\s/g, "");
      obj = JSON.parse(NewTxt);
      var NewStr = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < obj.jsontext.length; i++) {
        NewStr += obj.jsontext[i].name + "<br/>" + obj.jsontext[i].task + "<br/>" + obj.jsontext[i].date + "<br/>" + obj.jsontext[i].status + "<br/><br/>";
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = NewStr;
    }
  }
 });
```

and the HTML as:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```